# How to create dropdown with value and text node - WXPython

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, wxpython, wxwidgets

In HTML I can create drop-down menus like this:

```
<select name="">
    <option value="">TextNode #1</option>
    <option value="">TextNode #2</option>
<select>
```

Now I want something similar in wxPython.
The problem is that I have not found a solution, as it only allows me to place the text and not the value.

Example wxPython( Create Dropdown ):

```
DropDownList = []
Options = {0:"None",1:"All",2:"WTF?!!"}
For Value, TextNode in Options:
    DropDownList.append( TextNode )

wx.ComboBox(panel,value="Select",choices=DropDownList)
```

Well... How I can use a value addition to the text node?..
Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the ComboBox's Append method to add additional information to each item in the control.

Here's a tutorial about the process: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/12/16/wxpython-storing-object-in-combobox-or-listbox-widgets/

And here's a code example from the article:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class Car:
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, id, model, make, year):
        """Constructor"""
        self.id = id
        self.model = model
        self.make = make
        self.year = year       


########################################################################
class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Tutorial")

        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)

        cars = [Car(0, "Ford", "F-150", "2008"),
                Car(1, "Chevrolet", "Camaro", "2010"),
                Car(2, "Nissan", "370Z", "2005")]

        sampleList = []
        self.cb = wx.ComboBox(panel,
                              size=wx.DefaultSize,
                              choices=sampleList)
        self.widgetMaker(self.cb, cars)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.cb, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def widgetMaker(self, widget, objects):
        """"""
        for obj in objects:
            widget.Append(obj.make, obj)
        widget.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.onSelect)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onSelect(self, event):
        """"""
        print "You selected: " + self.cb.GetStringSelection()
        obj = self.cb.GetClientData(self.cb.GetSelection())
        text = """
        The object's attributes are:
        %s  %s    %s  %s

        """ % (obj.id, obj.make, obj.model, obj.year)
        print text

# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

According to my experience of using `wxWidgets` on c++, it's not supported natively.

What you could do is create a custom `wxComboBox` which would inherit from wxComboBox. Your custom widget will be responsible for storing the mapping, do a lookup everytime you call `SetValue` and do a reverse look up everytime you call `GetValue`

Comment: event.GetEventObject()  is better than accessing through self.cb